# Windows 7: User Permissions keep resetting for external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, permissions, external-hard-drive

**Help my Entire account is gone after following this advice**
i am sure that was not the goal. but it did happen i am afraid.

I am currently trying to solve icons not showing up on my external drive.
I think it might have to do with user permissions? Because nothing seems to refresh.

So what i tried to do is give all users full permission on that drive.
When i do that this random ID of a user pops up. That i can then remove.
But this random user with a random number still pops op on sub folders when i check there security.

I think the problem of this is. That when i set the permissions for all   users. And remove this random user. For some reason right after. Everything   is reset to the old setting again. Even after clicking apply.   Its like the drive just keeps hard resetting itself whenever i try to do   something.

I also have to give administrator rights for everything i do on the drive.   Its very annoying. even when i change names etc.

**extra visual info:**  [image: http://i.imgur.com/D7ITasX.png]

Regedit info: [image: http://i.imgur.com/ks4iRkf.png]

Comment: What command are you using exactly for taking ownership of all files and folders on the drive?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that sorry. Right clicked the folder and then went to the security tab. There where it says permissions for users. I ticked all of them on allow. Then when i apply it starts loading through all the sub folders but then just resets the permissions back to before. But with the exception of a new strange user id that is added. This user id also shows up before all this when i right click a folder inside the drive. I was trying to remove that before but then i get the following error. http://i.imgur.com/AWIPBmc.png  Thank you for helping!

Comment: You indicated you gave all users full permission on the drive.  I asked how you did this.

Comment: Oh i meant i gave the "user" part a tick for allow on every part that you can. on the first picture. there were it says allow and disallow. i put them all on allow when i do edit. but it just sets it back and it makes a new random user.

Comment: This just gives permission not ownership of the drive.  At some a user from another Windows installation took ownership of the root directory, Windows respects this ownership although its unable to determine who owns it.

Comment: Mhm yes. I took the ownership for it. It was indeed used by that random user id. But when i did this. It did not solve anything. And added extra errors like this one: http://i.imgur.com/wBDbr3Y.png - bit frustrating really. because my friend has no problems and can see icons and edit them on his external HDD. but i still cant by now. eep :/ - what do you suggest i do now?

Comment: What you describe, the process you used, did not take ownership of all files and folders on that drive.  You only added the user to the permission information. What I suggested, taking ownership of the file and folders, would result in that information being generated again.  If the same unknown user is coming back ( your other question ) then that explains it.  The context menu provided as answer would do that.

Comment: Ok so. To be honest. bit confused about what to do now heh. ^^
How do i go on about overwriting everything? Because that sounds good. Because i am not in a position right now to just format the drive. I am completely out of space. that's why i was gonna backup. But then i ran into this snowballing of problems. hehe ^^

Comment: Hope you have time soon to explain how i can overwrite all permissions.

Comment: Thank you Andre for editing my post to show the images! :)

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is properly give permission rights, to specific users, over a drive then I recommend using a "Take Ownership" context menu. It will save you dozens of clicks and a reboot or two.

It's worked for me in regards to internal/external drives and foreign/native users. Needless to say I haven't used anything else for quite some time. You can take ownership of files/folders in bulk and I've found it's more efficient at granting admin privileges than manually doing it.

It's a 1KB file so it doesn't take longer than 5 minutes to get the job done (depending on how many files you're taking ownership of). Check it out here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/
--- Raw info ---
Add Context Menu by saving as .Reg file, then execute.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Take Ownership"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t"
"IsolatedCommand"="cmd.exe /c takeown /f \"%1\" /r /d y && icacls \"%1\" /grant administrators:F /t"
```

If you change your mind you can remove the context menu this way:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
```

Comment: Pre-prepared .REG files are available here to accomplish these steps with a few clicks:  https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Take-Ownership-Menu-Hacks.zip

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions:

1. You format the drive (only do this if there is no important files onboard, or you've copied them off)
2. You change the ownership of the drive to you, then remove the user
   [image]
3. If the drive gets moved from PC to PC, make sure no other PC is writing permissions to the drive.
4. Check in the registry, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` that there is no user with that ID there (if there is, check for it in `control userpasswords2` or in the Local Users and groups manager `mmc`)
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

If there is no other user there, aside from yourself, Administrator and Guest, feel free to delete the registry key and restart.

PS: I'm logged in as the user `Administrator` so your config might look different

Comment: Leave the other 3, just remove the whole `key` and restart. the advanced permissions should remove the unknown account and leave the drive purged of that account. the restart is essential. then try the removal of permissions

Comment: Omg ... omg.... omg... i restarted my pc and everything reset. all my desktop gone. everything is gone. all my stuff. what am i supposed to do now.

Comment: Are you sure that you removed the long key? press CTRL+ALT+DEL and start Task Manager, check if explorer is stuck. if it is, kill it (right click on explorer, click end process) then restart explorer (File -> New Task) type explorer, hit enter. your desktop should be still there, as long as you didn't remove the key containing your user profile