# Entire Admin user gone. After i followed advice here. Stuck

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator, data-loss-prevention

I followed the advice here. And I am sure it was **Well meant**. But what I did made an entire new account. with almost the identical name. And gave me a brand new fresh desktop etc.

No offense meant towards the people helping. It's just caution.

**Chronological Order:**

1. I took all the steps that you see at the bottom of that Windows 7
   url
   [Windows 7: User Permissions keep resetting for external hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/899609/windows-7-user-permissions-keep-resetting-for-external-hard-drive)
   I followed the steps from. "Levi Pihema-Lindsay" at the bottom.
2. I removed the entry that was with the long numbers in regedit

   [image]
3. I made a backup of that entry before doing so.
4. Restarted my PC as told. but then i suddenly had a brand new desktop.
   it created a new account with the same name as the old one but then with a '.' behind it and another word.
5. yikes!

   [image]
6. I have allot of stuff on my old desktop. So I went into the old account at C:/users/ - and I moved the desktop stuff to my C:/ drive. Just to make sure I have it safely on C:/ and not in a users folder.

This does not solve my biggest problem though.
I had a very organized way of working with evernote and sticky notes.
So i need my old account and desktop back.

Now I am curious what will happen if I click my regedit backup. This was a tip given to me below. by megamorf - ty megamorf

Comment: Hey, you mentioned you followed advise on that thread, can you explain exactly what advise you followed as the first post mentions lots of 'potential fixes' but they are all different. Let me know exactly what steps you took and I'll try to help.

Comment: I added a What happened bit to my question. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: Did you by chance delete the registry information for a user you actually used, which the answer, didn't actually indicated to do?

Comment: the one from Levi Pihema-Lindsay at the bottom. i was told to remove the entry that says lots of numbers here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/95WFP.png i actually googled first how to back up an entry like that. because i was worried it might go wrong. so i do have a regedit entry backup thing. but im not sure if i should now merge that or not. with all this happening. dont know if that fixes it. cause i have new accounts now.

Comment: You are acting way to fast without knowing enough about what you are doing to understand what to do if something goes wrong, you need to slow down..  You obviously deleted the wrong entries.  If the new users are not named the same as the old users then you can restore what you deleted.

Comment: Yeah you are right. it was stupid of me. i trusted that that the other person knew it was ok or not. I did rush all of it. because i was running out of space. and i had to fix my HDD for backup. just RL is stressing also. etc etc. sorry.

Comment: So what sounds like has happened is that you've removed the registry entry which simply points your account login to its physical location (c:\users\username) however because that location exists it has created a new folder username.whatever. If you go back to c:\users and try to access the old location it should have all your files, you can simply copy these back to your new desktop....

Comment: Charles would that give my windows sticky's and favorites in folder sidebar and bookmarks and everything back aswell? because i tried to log into my evernote where all my clientell info is in. and it showed evernote as if i brand new reinstalled it. -- i would really like things to just be back to what it was. on my previous desktop before this happened.

Comment: I had a very organized way of doing things. thats why i had to fix my HDD because it did not wanna show icons. and i use icons for everything aswell.

Comment: Well it will and it wont. Most of the files for Evernote I would guess are kept in appdata which is a hidden folder in the root of your user profile. If you was to try and copy everything you might get lucky but its risky that could cause your new profile to become corrupt and then your back to delete the registry entry again to get a new profile....Might be the time to get it looked at first hand by an IT technician....

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Okay, based on what you've updated your original question with you need to do two things.

You deleted the registry key that basically acts as the bridge between user account and user profile. Without the key the account doesn't know that there's an existing user profile and tries to create one when you log in. Since there was already a profile with the name that it wanted to assign to the new profile it created a new profile that consists of the original name + a random string appended to it.

Please check your registry's profilelist once more and tell us if there's an entry similiar to the one you deleted earlier. If there is we just need to change it's profileimagepath value. If there isn't then we import your exported registry key.

The import needs to be done as administrator (a simple double click on the reg file will trigger the import).

---

If no registry backup of that key existed this would be my solution.

Ah, that means you've removed the entry that links your user account to your user profile.

1. Log in as administrator and rename the user profile in C:\users to something like "profilename.old" (you might want to **copy** it somewhere safe, too)
2. Create a new user (with the same name as the one you messed up) and log in as him and then log off
3. Log in as Administrator and **copy** the contents from C:\users\profilename.old to C:\users\profilename where profilename is the name of your profile

If you really have only removed that single entry in the registry then it's worth considering to recreate it:

Create a new user via the control panel. This will create a new entry for that user. Now Open `regedit` and browse to the new entry in the ProfileList. Right click > export to save it as .reg file. Open it with notepad and change the ProfileImagePath Entry to the name of your broken user account. Open Powershell and enter these lines (confirm each line with enter):

```
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("broken_username")
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
$strSID.Value
```

Replace broken_username with the user name that you have problems with. Then replace the sid in the reg file with the output from Powershell. Save and close the file. Double click it to import it. This should be all that you have to do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22734/discussion-on-answer-by-megamorf-entire-admin-user-gone-after-i-followed-advice).